# hovering issues in ie7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

http://indivar.us/ptcnews/

PLease check the above link. The first 3 menus in red does not show the proper popup on hover in IE7 but fine in other browsers.

Can you please help !!

Thanks
Balkar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use higher `z-index` value for `zone-menu-wrapper`

and lower `z-index` value for `zone-branding-wrapper` and `zone-content-wrapper`

**Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed)**

So your CSS should look like this:

```
 #zone-menu-wrapper {
    z-index:100;
    position: relative; /* or any desired position */
 }

 #zone-branding-wrapper, zone-content-wrapper  {
    z-index:99;
    position: relative; /* or any desired position */
 }
```